# Implications of changing Os level Virtual Memory setting and turning on LargeAddressAware flag?

Tags: c#, winforms, virtual-memory, performance-estimation

I am working on a legacy memory intensive dotnet application which reads data from database, process the data in memory and writes the process data to an external file in a single transaction.

Application is 64 bit written in wpf as front end and csharp and sql at back.

At the moment above transaction is executed in a series of programmatic batches depending on data selection by user.

I wanted to understand implications of doing Virtual Memory changes against 8 gb available RAM. Specifically what are the potential issues with these configurations?

Do I need to change the existing algorithm to see any performance benefit?

Comment: It is not very obvious what "virtual memory changes" might mean.  The /LARGEADDRESSAWARE option only has an affect on 32-bit code.  Nothing interesting to do in 64-bit code.

Comment: virtual memory changes are nothing but explicitly setting custom initial and maximum value of virtual memory instead of OS handling it. What possible implications this will have?